# java SimpleDateFormat returns a part of the time on windows

Tags: java, time-format

I am trying to get the current time and append it to the name of a file that I generate.

the code snippet:

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(app.values.getProperty("yyyy-MM-dd"));
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
String date = dtf.format(now);
Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
String time = timeFormat.format(today);
FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream("receipt/Receipt_" + date + "_"+time+".pdf");
```

This works fine on linux (returns "Receipt_2018-04-18_11:13" for the name of the file) but when I run the jar on windows 7, it only gives

```
Receipt_2018-04-18_11
```

and the generated file is damaged and empty. How can I fix this?

Comment: `:` is an illegal file character

Comment: Two issues: Since you can use the modern Java date and time types (`DateTimeFormatter` and `LocalDateTime`), I recommend you skip the old-fashioned and poorly designed classes completely (`Date`, `Calendar`and `SimpleDateFormat`). The modern classes have all the functionality you want. Mixing like you do will just confuse and risks incorrect results. (2) lowercase `hh` is for hour within AM or PM, from 01 through 12. Since you got no AM/PM marker, I think you want uppercase `HH` for hour of day, 00 through 23.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
String time = timeFormat.format(today);
FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream("receipt/Receipt_" + date + "_"+time+".pdf");
```

`:` is an illegal file character (under Windows at least, probably others).

For more information, have a look at [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx), it contains a list of invalid file/directory name characters

Maybe change it to `-`, for example

```
SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh-mm");
String time = timeFormat.format(today);
FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream("receipt/Receipt_" + date + "_"+time+".pdf");
```

or use `SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hhmm");` instead

## Update

So apparently fixing the immediate issue isn't enough for some people.

The `java.util.Date` classes are generally considered deprecated and you should instead make use of the newer (and improved) `java.time` API instead, for example...

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm");
FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream("receipt/Receipt_" + formatter.format(LocalDateTime.now()) + ".pdf");
```

Or, if you can't (use Java 8+), one of the many available libraries, including the back port for `java.time`

Comment: It's probably not good advice to tell someone to use the old and broken (stateful) `SimpleDateFormat` when they're already using the much better `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: @DavidConrad Agreed, but I focused on the primary issue on hand

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that ':' is incorrect character for the filenames on Windows OS, thus it needs to be replaced. Basically your code is excessive, you don't need `Calendar` since `LocalDateTime` already has timestamp part.

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd_hh_mm");
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
String dateTime = dtf.format(now);
FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream("receipt/Receipt_" + dateTime + ".pdf");
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

Try this i think it will work with you

For java.util.Date,  just create a new Date()

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");    Date date = new Date();     System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));
```